# Sitecore glassmapper not mapping fields inside field

Tags: glass-mapper

I have class CarouselViewModel as below

```
[SitecoreType]
    public class CarouselViewModel
    {
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Selected Items")]
        public IEnumerable<CarouselSlides> CarouselSlides { get; set; }
    }
```

The CarouselViewModel containes carouselSlides

```
[SitecoreType]
    public class CarouselSlides
    {
           [SitecoreField(FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Image, FieldName = "Image")]
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }


    }
```

Using glass mapper I am getting count as 3 in CarouselViewModel but the imagefield in individual carouselSlides is always coming as null. Is there something i am doing wrong while mapping the field. The field contains value and while using direct sitecore fields I am able to populate the model.

Comment: I don't know why this question was put on hold, I've seen several people have this issue before and as such may help others in the future.

Comment: Forgetting to inherit from GlassBase is a simple error; the resolution to which has nothing to do with the question title or image fields for that matter. Question and answer would need a lot of rework to be of any use for the records - e.g. something that would be useful and show up in a search engine search and provide an answer.

Comment: Also; holding and ultimately closing a question doesn't mean it's going away. Just means that OP had a problem and in this case OP found his own solution. No additional answers need to be added - and none would be useful anyway, given the misleading question and title.

Comment: The ultimate issue was not forgetting to inherit from Glassbase, it was not having a property for `[SitecoreId]` declared (which is included Glassbase). Unfortunately, since the question was put on hold, it means it could not be added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting the classes from GlassBase solved the issue

```
public class GlassBase
{
    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    string Name { get; set; }
    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateName)]
    string Template { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The Model should have worked as in your original code, but for Experience Editor mode you need to ensure a `[SitecoreId] public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }` is declared. This was more likely the issue (and what inheriting from `GlassBase` resolved - http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial5

Comment: Thanks jammykam, but the code was not working when it was not inherited from glassbase.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I'm telling you thr reason why. It's not necessary to inherit from Glassbase. Most likely you are using Codegen, Glassbase is not a requirement for those mnaully creating their models.